# Can chromecast on android project an RDP client

Tags: android, chromecast

If I get a Chromecast dongle and install an RDP client on my android phone (either Microsoft RDP or Chrome Remote Desktop), will I be able to project my RDP session from the Android phone to the Chromecast device?

Comment: Only if the RDP app supports Chome Cast. AFAIK that would require the app to decode the RDP stream and the encode it to a video stream and send it to the Chrome Cast dongle.

Comment: Well, I guess what I am asking is, do these RDP apps support Chromecast? Does anyone know this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Android apps don't belong here. Stackoverflow is for asking programming related questions.

Comment: You do whatever you think is right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that stumbles across this post, the answer is that "Google Chrome" supports two modes, in app streaming (most efficient) and whole screen streaming (just mirrors you phone screen on the TV/monitor). There is no in app streaming option for the RDP clients, but it will happily work with the screen cast option.